# Can extract one JSON element, can;t extract the one before it

Tags: javascript, json, firebug

I have these three lines in a row:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dash.groupList[x], null, 2));
console.log("dash.groupList[x].newItem.id = "+dash.groupList[x].newItem.id);
console.log("dash.groupList[x].newItem.label = "+dash.groupList[x].newItem.label);
```

Which produces this in the console:

```
{
  "index": 1,
  "name": "Targeting Criteria 2",
  "items": [],
  "newItem": {
    "id": "any_web",
    "label": "Any Data",
    "tooltip": "Search web data on file.",
    "template": "one_opt",
    "exclusive": true,
    "term": "True"
  },
  "$$hashKey": "object:381"
}
dash.groupList[x].newItem.id = 
dash.groupList[x].newItem.label = Any Data
```

How come I can pull label , but not id?

Comment: Probably a bug outside of this that you're not noticing.  Can you produce a jsfiddle to replicate?

Comment: the JSON is valid so this should work (if nothing else was effecting it)

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/uwvrzk5L/)

Comment: Maybe JSON.stringify is converting a mostly-valid JSON string into a valid-looking JSON string. You could try re-parsing the stringify-ed version: `var v=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dash.groupList[x], null, 2));` and then try `console.log(v.newItem.label);`. You could also look at what Firebug says you got from the server under the network tab and see if it looks the same as what you got from stringify.

Comment: Thanks, @LinuxDisciple, the id's are returning empty. There's no network involved at this point.

Comment: @tyler I'll try, this is part of a cakephp project and the object in question has been passed around a lot

Comment: How is this bug related to Firebug? Is it working in the Firefox or Chrome developer tools?